# SQL Case Reference

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

Using the code below (thank you @BHouse), I am attempting to adjust "ECOMMERCE" selling price to reflect "ENFIELD" selling price. As you can see from results, I am getting multiple entries.

[Results can been seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DSFQ.png)

```
SELECT 
T1.STRTRADECODE AS [STORE],
T1.LINTITEMNUMBER AS [SKU],
CASE WHEN T1.STRTRADECODE = 'ECOMMERCE' THEN T2.CURNORMALSELL ELSE T1.CURNORMALSELL END AS [SELLINGPRICE]

FROM DAILYSALES T1
LEFT JOIN DAILYSALES T2 ON T1.LINTITEMNUMBER = T2.LINTITEMNUMBER AND T1.STRTRADECODE <> T2.STRTRADECODE

WHERE 
T1.DTMTRADEDATE >= '2018-01-02 00:00:00' 
AND T1.STRSALETYPE = 'I'
AND T1.STRTRADECODE IN ('ECOMMERCE', 'ENFIELD') 
AND T1.LINTITEMNUMBER = '18760'

GROUP BY
T1.STRTRADECODE,
T1.LINTITEMNUMBER,
T1.CURNORMALSELL,
T2.CURNORMALSELL

ORDER BY
T1.STRTRADECODE DESC
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `Store 2's selling price`? Show your table(s), columns and what you have tried

Comment: Date  Store  Selling Price
=====  ======  =============
01.01.18         Store1  1.00
01.01.18         Store2  2.00
01.01.18         Store3  2.50
01.01.18         Store3  2.50

Comment: So you want to show the STORE2, STORE3 records with their price, but the STORE1 records with the STORE2 price for the same date? Don't use comments for this. Edit your request instead and show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: Thorsten, yes. I would like to adjust the Store1 price to always refer to Store2 price.

Comment: we will appreciate with any script you have tried so far, please paste it here

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to SQL and honestly do not know where to begin. :(

Comment: Problem updated!

Answer (score 0):

Added Sku to the table , matching `Sku` and different store numbers will retrieve selling value for store2.

This query will help u, to use values matching another store

```
SELECT T1.STRTRADECODE AS [STORE], T1.LINTITEMNUMBER AS [SKU], T2.CURNORMALSELL AS [SELLINGPRICE]
FROM DAILYSALES T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM DAILYSALES
    WHERE name = 'enfield'
    ) t2
    ON t1.sku = t2.sku
WHERE T1.DTMTRADEDATE >= '2018-01-02 00:00:00' AND T1.STRSALETYPE = 'I' AND T1.STRTRADECODE IN (
        'ECOMMERCE'
        ,'ENFIELD'
        ) AND T1.LINTITEMNUMBER = '18760'
ORDER BY T1.STRTRADECODE DESC
```

sample:

```
      DECLARE @testtable TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), name VARCHAR(100), sellingPrice FLOAT, sku BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @testtable (name, sellingPrice, sku)
SELECT 'Enfield', '60.50', '16043853021'

UNION

SELECT 'Ecommerce', '190.50', '16043853021'

UNION

SELECT 'Enfield', '120.45', '06062829018'

UNION

SELECT 'Ecommerce', '180.45', '06062829018'

;

select distinct t.id,t.name,t.sku,t2.sellingPrice 
from @testtable t Inner  join (select * from  @testtable where name = 'enfield') t2
on t.sku = t2.sku
```

Comment: @B house, yes this is perfect. Thank you. Is there a way to include an additional variable into the mix? For example, use store 2's selling price if its store 1 AND SKU number matches?

Comment: @Kajan edited script to meet the SKU requirements, let me know if this works

Comment: @B House, I have amended my problem. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: @kajan You do not need to group by , as u dont have any aggregate function in Select query

Comment: @B House, that was to try and shrink the number of records. 

Overall I am still getting multiple selling prices for "ECOMMERCE". Not sure how to address this issue.

Comment: @kajan use distinct after select statement